# Login-AzureRMAccount noninteractive fails with org account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I am able to login Login-AzureRmAccount with popup window. I need do use noninteractive mode in VSTS CI host. When I try following on my computer:

```
$username = "my org login"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "Mypass" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential($username,$pass)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

I got message:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS 
metadata exchange failed: The underlying con
nection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], 
AadAuthenticationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

I ran out of ideas.

Comment: any chance you have MFA enabled?

Comment: @4c74356b41  99% that MFA is enabled. Is it AAD or user specific? I can request admin for technical account with MFA disabled then

Comment: I will try with Service Principal [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-addservprinc-admins)

Answer (score 1):

You cant use silent auth for accounts with MFA enabled. You have to go some other route.

Comment: I will try with Service Principar described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-addservprinc-admins)

Comment: sure, please accept this answer as it answers your question :)